# Return when 1 value is bigger than another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains hardware items. The item and their manufacturer are contained in the table together with a price. I need to return the manufacturer;'s name when one of its items is more expensive that the other.

For example, in the table below I only want to return the manufacturer's name when the 10mm is a higher cost than the 5mm.

**Table**

```
╔══════════════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ Manufacturer ║ Size ║ Cost  ║
╠══════════════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ Acme         ║ 5mm  ║ 10.00 ║
║ Acme         ║ 10mm ║ 20.00 ║
║ AAA          ║ 5mm  ║ 15.00 ║
║ AAA          ║ 10mm ║ 14.00 ║
║ BBB          ║ 5mm  ║ 17.00 ║
║ BBB          ║ 10mm ║ 20.00 ║
╚══════════════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Is this example, I only want to return manufacturers that have a more expensive 10mm item. So the table above would only return 2 rows:

**Desired Output**

```
Acme 
BBB
```

Comment: use a subquery - post it if it fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` like this

```
SELECT Manufacturer 
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Manufacturer 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Size = '10mm' THEN Cost END) > MAX(CASE WHEN Size = '5mm' THEN Cost END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` window function for this:

```
select * from
    (select *, row_number() over(partition by Manufacturer order by Cost desc) rn 
     from TableName) t
where rn = 1 and size = 10
```